# When does an anonymous function execute if defined as a functions parameter?

Tags: javascript

```
//The anonymous function is not being executed there in the parameter. 
//The item is a callback function
$("#btn_1").click(function() {
  alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
});
```

If the anonymous function is not being executed in the parameters of the main function, then how do you execute the anonymous function inside the body of the main function?

Something like this:

```
function myFunction(function(){ /*code inside anon function */ }){ /*Code insider main function */} 

/*Calling the main function */
myFunction();
```

when does anoymous function get executed?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The anonymous function gets executed by the click event handler.

Comment: I think you are overthinking IIFEs, look them up ;-) Here the function will be run when the element is clicked

Comment: Each time the click event is fired on `$("btn_1")` that's when the anonymous function will execute.

Comment: What does `console.log($("#btn_1")[0])` log?

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you have a specific problem..tell us what it is. If this is a curiosity question then try to elaborate on your confusion

Comment: Something like this:
function myFunction(function(){ // code inside anonymous function}){
//Code insider main function
}

//Calling the main function, when does anoymous function get executed?
myFunction();

Comment: I have edited the post, please take a look

Comment: "I have edited the post" - That declaration is invalid. The code will fail to parse, so your anonymous function will never get executed.

Answer (score 0):

From your edit, it looks like you have the function declaration and the function callback mixed up.

If a function takes another function as a parameter it will look something like:

```js
// myFunction accepts a function as a parameter
function myFunction(fn){
  //call the passed in function
  fn() // fn is the function you passed in
}

// Calling the main function and pass in function
myFunction(function(){ 
  console.log("hello")
  }
);
```

So in your original example:

```
$("#btn_1").click(function() {
  alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
});
```

`click()` is defined to accept a function, which you passed in. It is analogous to `myFunction` above except the browser waits to get a click before it calls the function you passed in.

So in answer to your original question:

> then how do you execute the anonymous function inside the body of the main function?

The answer is, in the case of event handlers like `click()` you don't, the browser does.